# What is the reason of this output from for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

```
void    f() {
for (i == 0; i < 6 && i++, i <10; i++)
   {
       printf("%d", i);
   }
}
int main()
{
f();
return 0;
}
```

[Codes Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EldqU.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkuEG.png)

Any tips on how to debug for loops on paper without a computer

Comment: Why do you post your output as a picture? As fa as I can see your output is only text. Please don't post pictures of text but post text as text.

Answer (score 5):

In the code, by saying `i == 0` (comparison operator) instead of `i = 0` (assignment operator), in the successive use, you're using an uninitialized local variable, which has indeterminate value.

That said, the correct version should look like

```
#include <stdio.h>           //header file is needed

void f() {
for (int i = 0; i < 6 && i++, i <10; i++)    // define types
   {
       printf("%d", i);
   }
}

int main(void)                               // correct signature
{           
    f();                                     // indent, optional but good
    return 0;
}
```